# authenticate returns nothing

Tags: python, django, django-models

what im experimenting is the next:

```
S:\proj>manage.py shell
Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) django 1.1.1

>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User(username='luis', password='admin')
>>> u.save() #sucessfull created in mysql db
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> usuario = authenticate(username='luis', password='admin')
>>> usuario
>>>
```

authenticate return nothing, what I am missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is not with `authenticate`, but with your creation of the user.

The value stored in `u.password` needs to be the hashed value of the password, not the raw password itself.

You can use `u.set_password('password')` to take care of the hashing for you:

```
>>> u = User(name='luis')
>>> u.set_password('password')
>>> u.save()
>>> authenticate(username='luis', password='password')
<User: luis>
```

Comment: faaaaaaaaaaaaast and furiousssssss