# Unable to authenticate user using authenticate()

Tags: django

I'm trying to authenticate an user, but using `authenticate()`, django (1.4) returns `None`... I tried to manually query the db:

```
select * from auth_user where password = THE_PASSWORD
```

and I get the expected user back.
I tried to debug using breakpoints and I discovered that `check_password()` function in `django.contrib.auth.hashers` is returning `False` in `hasher.verify()`... but honestly I don't know why and how to dig further into the problem... any idea?

ps. I did not modify my original `SECRET_KEY`

**UPDATE:**

OMG... I finally figured out the problem! In practice in my application I have a form for user signup, once a user submit that form he will receive an email with an activation link, which sets the user as "active"... I would like to implement an "auto-login" once the user has been activated through the link and in order to do this I was trying to authenticate him using the hashed password (that is the only one I can retrieve programmatically), BUT django authenticate() expects the raw password, since it's the one the user manually write in the login form and for security reason it can't be regenerated starting from the hashed one stored in the database...
So, I was fundamentally following a bad practice... it seems to me that the right move is instead to present to the user a new page saying: "congratulations, your account has been activated... Now you can actually login using this new form :)"

Comment: Does this help? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1947811/authenticate-returns-nothing

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't, since I'm already storing the hashed password using set_password() method before calling save() :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're manually querying the database with the raw password and successfully returning the user, that means that you have stored the raw password, not the hashed one, in the database. Naturally, Django's  attempt to find the hashed password in the db will fail.

Note that Django, not you, is doing the right thing here: you *must* store the hashed password, not the raw one.

Comment: I stored the hashed one!(using set_password())

Comment: I've accepted your answer, since although it does not provide the solution to my problem, it helped my brain to find it! :)